# Hide/show table rows with a specific class name when clicked another row with a different class name? in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I am trying to implement table row toggle functionality in angular 2 . Two types of table row with different classes are displayed in a loop from the data retrieved. some thing like this .

```
<table>
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody class="data-item" *ngFor = "let member of teamMember" >
            <tr class="default">
                <td *ngFor = "let hrs of member.Value.hoursLogged">
                    {{ hrs }}
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="toggle-row" *ngFor = "let subtask of member.Value.subTasks">
                <td *ngFor="let hrs of subtask.subtaskHoursLogged">
                    {{ hrs }}
                </td>
            </tr>
    <tbody>
</table>
```

question is how do i toggle table row with class toggle-row when clicking on table row with class default.

my json file ist like this

```
[
    {
        "name": "Timothy Clogg",
        "Position":"Project Manager",
        "imgUrl":"http://www.theappvillage.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/David_McGowan_portrait_square.png",
        "hoursLogged":[ 1.2, " ",2.3, 4.5, 5.6,3.1, " " ],
        "totalHours":15.91,
        "totalMoney":"$1234.12",
        "toggle":1,
        "subTasks":[
            {
                "taskType":"consulting",
                 "subtaskHoursLogged":[ 1.2, " ",2.3, 4.5, 5.6,3.1, " " ],
                 "subtaskTotalHour":3.45,
                 "subtaskMoney":"$234.45"
            },
            {
                "taskType":"consulting",
                 "subtaskHoursLogged":[ 1.2, " ",2.3, 4.5, 5.6,3.1, " " ],
                 "subtaskTotalHour":3.45,
                 "subtaskMoney":"$234.45"
            },
            {
                "taskType":"consulting",
                 "subtaskHoursLogged":[ 1.2, " ",2.3, 4.5, 5.6,3.1, " " ],
                 "subtaskTotalHour":3.45,
                 "subtaskMoney":"$234.45"
            }
        ]
    },
   {data},
   {data}
 ]
```

,

Answer (score 1):

You can use the hidden and class property binding to achieve this as below,

```
 <tbody class="data-item" *ngFor = "let member of teamMember" >
            <tr [class.toggle-row]="!member.toggle" [class.default]="member.toggle" [hidden]="member.toggle">
                <td *ngFor = "let hrs of member.Value.hoursLogged">
                    {{ hrs }}
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr [hidden]="!member.toggle" [class.toggle-row]="!member.toggle" [class.default]="member.toggle" *ngFor = "let subtask of member.Value.subTasks">
                <td *ngFor="let hrs of subtask.subtaskHoursLogged">
                    {{ hrs }}
                </td>
            </tr>
    <tbody>
```

Note: `member.toggle` property must be added to the json

Comment: thank u very much for the quick response my json like that, just edited question,  i only included few lines of code to reduce complexity, should toggle be a key with boolean value ?

Comment: yes. exactly. if you need more help reach me in fb @ aravind2109